# Using preprocessor definitions in iOS App info.plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iOS app that uses SSO with Facebook as part of getting your app to work with Facebook's SSO you have to specify the FacebookAppId and callback url in the info.plist. I have 2 different Facebook groups one for testing and one for production. I want to be able to have the values of the two keys specified above set based on preprocessor directives.

In my MessageBomb-Prefix.pch i have the following, which works fine:

```
#ifdef TEST
    //Development environments
    #define PARSE_APP_ID "dev parse app id"
    #define PARSE_CLIENT_ID "dev parse client id"
    #define FB_APP_ID "dev facebook id"
#else
    //Production environments
    #define PARSE_APP_ID "prod parse app id"
    #define PARSE_CLIENT_ID "prod parse client id"
    #define FB_APP_ID "prod facebook id"
#endif
```

However in my info.plist i have done the below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb${FB_APP_ID}</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>${FB_APP_ID}</string>
```

Is it even possible to do what i'm trying to do. I've set the project to preprocess the info.plist.

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Do you have it enabled in project settings by setting Preprocess Info.plist File to Yes ?

Comment: @AndrewTetlaw you should make that an answer. (And perhaps include some details about how to specify the preprocessor include files?)

Answer (score 17):

If you go into Build Settings you can set `Preprocess Info.plist File` to `YES` and then set `Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File` to a `.h` file you've placed in your project with `#define` directives.

So for example if I add a key to my `Info.plist` file: `testKey` with the value `TEST_VALUE`. Then I place `test.h` in my project with:

```
#define TEST_VALUE hello_world
```

And then I set `Preprocess Info.plist File` to `YES` and `Info.plist Preprocessor Prefix File` to `test.h`

The value of that key, when retrieved is now "hello_world". If you change the value of the macro a lot you may find you need to do Product/Clean to see changes because XCode seems to cache the compiled value.

Comment: I can't find the "Preprocess Info.plist File" setting in Xcode 4.6 anymore. Anyone know how to modify it?

Comment: I do product clean and even delete the derived data and it still uses my old Facebook app id value. I have to rebuild and re-clean and delete the cache about 20 times for the new changes.

Answer (score 9):

To access in plist:

**Create a new variable**
[image]

---

**Define it**
[image]

---

**Use it in your info plist**
[image]

Comment: Sorry, not able to access user-defines in code directly. You need to add to "preprocessor macros". You may write a preprocessor macro which declares to the value of the user define "FOO=${FOO}". Then you can access FOO in code.

Answer (score 8):

The Info.plist preprocessor will let you use build settings in your Info.plist, not `#define`s. So you can define `FB_APP_ID` as a custom user build setting in your target (and give it overrides for different schemes), and this value will then be available to Info.plist. However, user build settings don't get exposed to your code. That is, unless you muck with your Preprocessor Definitions build setting and add an entry that looks like

```
FB_APP_ID=@\"$(FB_APP_ID)\"
```

(the backslashes are required to get the double-quotes past the shell invocation)

If your app ID may contain spaces, then you'll need to add quotes to get past the shell invocation:

```
FB_APP_ID="@\"$(FB_APP_ID)\""
```

In the end, you'll have build settings that looks something like this:

[image: Build settings]

Comment: for those wondering how to use a user-defined build setting in the plist file, set the value like so, assuming you made a user-defined build setting named IS_FILE_SHARING_ENABLED: 
<string>${IS_FILE_SHARING_ENABLED}</string>